# What do you call someone who leads a visitor from the office reception to the office premises

Tags: single-word-requests, terminology

What is the name of the person who takes a visitor (guest, client, etc.) from the reception area to the inside of the office premises?

Many times when we will go to office, the office receptionist call to an employee to let the visitor inside the facility.

For example:

> The photocopier repairman is here. 
>   We need a ______ to take him to the photocopier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regular employee who accompanies a visitor is called an ***escort***.